# Recursive finding of the number of paths in a graph.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion

> A directed graph $G_n = \langle V_n, E_n \rangle$ is defined as follows:
> \begin{array}{r c l}
> V_n &=& \{ x_i : i=0, \dots, n \} \cup \{ y_i, z_i : i=1, \dots, n \}, \\
> E_n &=& \{ x_i \to x_{i+1}, x_i \to y_{i+1}, x_i \to z_{i+1} : i=0, \dots, n-1 \} \cup \\\
> & & \{ y_i \to x_i : z_i \to x_i : i=1, \dots, n \} \cup \\&& \{ y_i \to y_{i+1}, z_i \to z_{i+1} : i=1, \dots, n-1 \}.
> \end{array}
> Let $a_n$ denote the number of directed paths from $x_0$ to $x_n$. Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n)^{1/n}$.

Graph for $n=4$:

[image]

My Solution:

Let $b_n$ denote the number of directed paths from $x_0$ to $y_n$, and $c_n$ the directed paths from $x_0$ to $z_n$.

We have $a_n = a_{n-1} + b_n + c_n$, (since you can reach $x_n$ from $x_{n-1}$, $y_n$ or $z_n$), and since $b_n$ and $c_n$ are the same we have $a_n = a_{n-1} + 2b_{n}$.
Then $b_n = b_{n-1} + a_{n-1}$ (since you can reach $y_n$ from $y_{n-1}$ or $x_{n-1}$).

So finally we have the system of equations
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_n = a_{n-1}+2b_{n}+\color{black}{[n=0]}\\
b_n=b_{n-1}+a_{n-1}
\end{eqnarray*}
where $a_0 = 1$ and $b_0 = 0$. $[n=0]$  is an [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

However, in the answers, there is the system of equations:

$$
\begin{array}{c}{{a_{n}=a_{n-1}+2b_{\color{blue}{n-1}}+\color{black}{[n=0]}}}\\
{{b_{n}=a_{n-1}+\color{blue}{3b_{n-1}}}}\end{array} 
$$

Why is my answer wrong? Where do these differences come from?

Comment: Your starting values should rather be $x_0 = 1$ and $y_0 = 0$.

Comment: @CiaPan Makes sense, I have edite my post. This also explains Iverson's bracket.

Comment: Equation $x_n = x_{n-1} + y_n + z_n$ becomes $x_n = x_{n-1} + 2y_{n}$, not $x_n = x_{n-1} + 2y_{n-1}$.

Comment: Are you sure about $y_{n}=y_{n-1}+x_{n-1}+\color{blue}{2y_{n-1}}$ in the answer? It seems strange they did not write $3y_{n-1}$

Comment: I am finding your notation to be quite confusing. How can you have $a_n=x_n$? Isn't $a_n$ a positive integer whereas $x_n$ a vertex? Please advise

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni It says $2y_{n-1}$, but there have been mistakes in these solutions many times already, so it's very possible that it's wrong.

Comment: @Mike $x_n$ is the number of paths to the $n$-th vertex $x$. Meanwhile, $a_n$ is the result we are looking for. In our case, the result is the number of paths to the mentioned vertex, so $a_n = x_n$. I apologize for the ambiguity.

Comment: @Michal If they have written $y_{n-1}+2y_{n-1}$ without simplifying it into $3y_{n-1}$, that's surely a typo.

Comment: @Michał you need to clarify your notation in your post, please. There is no need for this ambiguity. Especially since you already defined $x_n$ to be a vertex and $a_n$ and the number of paths to $x_n$. Keep in mind that a question on MSE has to make sense to not only the OP and those answering it, but those who read this after for a reference.  I downvoted this for now, fix this and I will remove.

Comment: I suggest making $a_n$ the number of paths from $x_0$ to $x_n$; then $b_n$ the number of paths from $x_0$ to $y_n$; and finally $c_n$ the number of paths from $x_0$ to $z_n$.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni Maybe they left it like that so it's easier to see where the recursion came from, because there is no description. There are only these equations and the final answer, which is $2+\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: @Mike Now it should be better.

Comment: It is better thank you, please explain by what you mean by [$n = 0$] though.

Comment: @Mike This is an [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket). I used it so that the recursive equation holds, i.e. so that $a_0 = 1$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Mike's definition of $a_n$ being the number of paths from $x_0$ to $x_n$ and $b_n$ being the number from $x_0$ to $y_n$, the recursion is $$
\begin{align}
b_0 &= 0,\\
a_0 &= 1,\\
b_n &= b_{n-1}+a_{n-1} \; \text{for}\; n \ge 2, \; \text{and}\\
a_n &= a_{n-1}+2 b_n \;\text{for}\; n \ge 2.
\end{align}
$$
To operate at the degenerate $n=0$ level, we may imagine virtual $y_0$ and $z_0$ nodes with appropriate arrows leaving them to mimic the other levels.
We may then delete these arrows because $b_0 = 0$ makes no contribution.

We may reduce the above to the single second-order recursion $$
\begin{align}
a_0 &= 1,\\
a_1 &= 3,\; \text{and}\\
a_n &= 4a_{n-1}-a_{n-2} \;\text{for}\; n \ge 2.
\end{align}
$$
This is sequence [A001835](https://oeis.org/A001835) in the OEIS (offset by 1).  The characteristic equation of this recursion is $r^2-4r+1 = 0$, which has roots $2\pm \sqrt{3}$.  Thus the limiting value of $(a_n)^{1/n}$ is $2+\sqrt{3}$.  We can also write the full solution for $a_n$ for completeness:  $$
a_n = \frac{3+\sqrt{3}}{6} (2+\sqrt{3})^n + \frac{3-\sqrt{3}}{6} (2-\sqrt{3})^n.
$$

Comment: How do you know it's $2+\sqrt{3}$
 instead of $2−\sqrt{3}$? I mean without finding full solution for
$a_n$, because then one can just calculate the limit. Also, thanks for the answer; it's good to know that my system of equations was correct.

Comment: The asymptotic behavior is determined by which root $r$ has the largest absolute value, because if $|r_1| > |r_2|$, then $|r_2^n/r_1^n| \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.